# How can I get my own user attributes (Email, UPN etc.) from Azure AD by using an interactive login?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to write a C# console app to get my own user attributes (such as businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, jobTitle, mail, mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname, and userPrincipalName) from Azure AD by using an interactive login? Using the standard login Windows that pops up when authenticating to AAD.

I started by doing this but 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory' is deprecated.

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string clientId = "my client ID from app reg";
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-tenant-id";
        string resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
```

Comment: Are you registered with MS Entra? If not, then no.

Comment: Yes. I have also registered an App and got a ClientID (AppID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Azure AD application and grant User.Read API permission:

[image]

Generate the auth-code by using below endpoint and sign-in with the user account:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://replyUrlNotSet
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

**You can make use of below code to get the singed in user details:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };
        var tenantId = "TenantID";
        var clientId = "ClientID";
        var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
        var authorizationCode = "authcodefromabove";

        var options = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, authorizationCode, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authCodeCredential, scopes);

        try
        {
            // Fetch user details using GET request to Microsoft Graph API
            var result = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();

            // Output user details
            Console.WriteLine($"User ID: {result.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Display Name: {result.DisplayName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Email: {result.Mail}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Job Title: {result.JobTitle}");
            // Add more properties as needed

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error fetching user details: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

***Modify the code and use the below to get the details you require:***

```cs
    try
        {
            var result = await graphClient.Me
                .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                {
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "displayName", "id", "officeLocation", "givenName", "businessPhones", "jobTitle", "mobilePhone", "preferredLanguage", "surname", "userPrincipalName", "mail" };
                });

            // Output user details
            Console.WriteLine($"User ID: {result.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Display Name: {result.DisplayName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Email: {result.Mail}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Job Title: {result.JobTitle}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Business Phones: {string.Join(",", result.BusinessPhones)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Given Name: {result.GivenName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Mobile Phone: {result.MobilePhone}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Office Location: {result.OfficeLocation}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Preferred Language: {result.PreferredLanguage}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Surname: {result.Surname}");
            Console.WriteLine($"User Principal Name: {result.UserPrincipalName}");
            // Add more properties as needed

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error fetching user details: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

And get response like below:

[image]

**UPDATE: To make use of Interactive browser credential flow make use of below code:**

Enable Public client flow:

[image]

Add the redirect URI in **Mobile and desktop applications** platform:

[image]

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };


var tenantId = "TenantID";
var clientId = "ClientID";
var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    // MUST be http://localhost or http://localhost:PORT
    // See https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/System-Browser-on-.Net-Core
    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
};

// https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.interactivebrowsercredential
var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

        try
        {
            // Fetch user details using GET request to Microsoft Graph API
            var result = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();

            // Output user details
            Console.WriteLine($"User ID: {result.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Display Name: {result.DisplayName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Email: {result.Mail}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Job Title: {result.JobTitle}");
            // Add more properties as needed

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error fetching user details: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your response. Please see the comment below.

Comment: Make use of `graphClient.Me.GetAsync` instead of `graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();`

Comment: Your code is still using a 'clientsecret'. Is there a way to replace  var clientSecret = "ClientSecret"; var authorizationCode = "authcodefromabove"; by an interactive login? Like the Azure AD login box.

Comment: Do you want to use client certificate instead of secret? or you do not want to use client secret at all?

Comment: I don't want to use a secret at all. I want to use a InteractiveBrowserCredential();

Comment: If you do not want to use client secret then mark the application as Public like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/PBG2KOT.png)

Comment: For interactive browser credential flow make use of the code refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#interactive-provider

Comment: Perfect. I am almost there. I get this message but I think this might be something to do with the app configuration. Error fetching user details: InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.

Comment: Please check the Updated answer to resolve the error

Comment: To resolve the error Enable Public client flow and Add the redirect URI in Mobile and desktop applications platform

Comment: My friend, you are a legend. I wish I were as smart as you. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad that you resolved the issue

Comment: Hello again, Rukmini. I was hoping you could help or point me in the right direction. The code worked perfectly until I upgraded to Windows 11 23H1 a few days ago. I started to get this error [[[ Error message: InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The download has failed (the connection was interrupted). ]]]]]] . Looks like the token is getting cached. But this is just an uninformed guess.

Comment: + I should add that the code works arbitrarily every second, third, or fourth try. Sometimes, it brings up the login screen; sometimes, it does not. When it does, it sometimes draws down the user properties, and sometimes it does not. It never draws down the user properties if the login screen does not show.

Comment: Please post the new question with all the requirements

Comment: Thanks for that. I've created a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78175193/interactivebrowsercredential-authentication-failed-the-browser-based-authentica

Answer (score 0):

I tried to amend your code to use an interactive login instead of a Client Secret. But I get the following error.  'MeRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Request' and no accessible extension method 'Request' accepting a first argument of type 'MeRequestBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };
        var tenantId = "9fa4d4d6-7541-490f-a49a-111d3392731f";
        var clientId = "45eca948-6cdd-4b98-ad9b-7aa6b36038c4";

        // Create an interactive credential
        var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential();

        // Authenticate with Microsoft Graph
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

        try
        {
            // Fetch user details using GET request to Microsoft Graph API
            var result = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

            // Output user details
            Console.WriteLine($"User ID: {result.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Display Name: {result.DisplayName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Email: {result.Mail}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Job Title: {result.JobTitle}");
            // Add more properties as needed
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error fetching user details: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```