# InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The download has failed

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

Error message: InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The download has failed (the connection was interrupted)

The goal is to get my own user attributes (Email, UPN etc.) from Azure AD by using an interactive login? I do not want to use a certificate or secret.

The following code worked perfectly until I upgraded to Windows 11 23H1 a few days ago. Looks like the token is getting cached. But this is just an uninformed guess.

I should add that the code works arbitrarily every second, third, or fourth try. Sometimes, it brings up the login screen; sometimes, it does not.

When it does, it sometimes draws down the user properties, and sometimes it does not.

It never draws down the user properties if the login screen does not show.

```
static async Task getMyDetailsFromAzure(string tenantId, string clientId, string logToFile)
{
    try
    {
        RegistryKey keyHKCU = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\AppName", true);
        try
        {
            if (keyHKCU == null)
            {
                keyHKCU = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\AppName");
            }
        }
        catch { }

        if (keyHKCU != null)
        {

            string[] requiredAttribs = {
            "BusinessPhones"
            ,"City"
            ,"CompanyName"
            ,"Country"
            ,"Department"
            ,"DisplayName"
            ,"EmployeeId"
            ,"FaxNumber"
            ,"GivenName"
            ,"JobTitle"
            ,"Mail"
            ,"MailNickname"
            ,"MobilePhone"
            ,"OfficeLocation"
            ,"PostalCode"
            ,"State"
            ,"StreetAddress"
            ,"Surname"
            ,"UserPrincipalName"};
            var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };
            var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
            {
                TenantId = tenantId,
                ClientId = clientId,
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                RedirectUri = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"),
            };
            var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

            try
            {
                
                var result = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                {
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = requiredAttribs;
                });
                
                var propertyNames = result.GetType().GetProperties();

                foreach (var property in propertyNames)
                {
                    if (requiredAttribs.Contains(property.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        if (property.Name.ToLower().Equals("businessphones"))
                        {
                            int counter = 1;
                            foreach (var phone in result.BusinessPhones)
                            {
                                if (phone != null)
                                    try
                                    {
                                        keyHKCU.SetValue("az_" + property.Name.ToLower() + counter, phone);
                                        counter = counter + 1;
                                    }
                                    catch { }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (property.GetValue(result) != null)
                                try
                                {
                                    keyHKCU.SetValue("az_" + property.Name.ToLower(), property.GetValue(result));
                                }
                                catch { }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cLogger.WriteToFileThreadSafe($"Error fetching user details from Azure AD (1) : {ex.Message}", logToFile);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cLogger.WriteToFileThreadSafe($"Could not create the registry path.", logToFile);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex) { cLogger.WriteToFileThreadSafe($"Error fetching user details from Azure AD (2) : {ex.Message}", logToFile); }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a workaround for my question. I used the class '**BrowserCustomizationOptions**' and requested that the application use the **default browser** instead of the **EmbeddedWebView** browser.

```
    var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost:5453"),
    BrowserCustomization = new BrowserCustomizationOptions {
        ErrorMessage = "Authentication failed",
        SuccessMessage = "Authentication succeeded",
        UseEmbeddedWebView = false,
    }
};
```