MS Graph to manage AAD B2C accounts
I have implemented an application to manage AAD B2C accounts using MS Graph. I followed this link and have registered a MS Graph application in my B2C tenant. Right now my implementation uses client credentials provider and I am able to create/modify users.
I am now planning to add a log in page. I have a sign-in/sign-up user flow that uses authorization code flow grant and has Entra ID  as an external IDP. Is delegated access (access on behalf of Entra user/account) to Graph API possible in this case? If not, is it ok to continue using app-only access?
EDIT (5/30/2024)
Honestly, I am wondering if the delegated access makes sense in this case. But again, my understanding may be completely wrong (and do correct me if that is the case). So, the scenario is: a user in an external AAD is logged into my application and is trying to manage the local accounts in the B2C tenant. My understanding of delegated access is that a user consents to the access, of some resource, by the application on their behalf. But what is the permission of the user to begin with? They don't have an ownership or authority over the resource defined anywhere unlike the application for which the API permission is configured.
Would it make more sense to pass group/role claims in the token from AAD and use that for access control (for instance, allow the logged in user to click on the "user management" menu or not) but the graph API access will still be app-only (client credentials flow)?

Note that: An Azure AD B2C application configured to support "Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)" only supports the Microsoft Graph permissions for offline_access and openid in a delegated manner.

If you want to make use of other delegated Microsoft Graph API permissions, you need to register the application by selecting "Accounts in this organizational directory only (Tenant only - Single tenant)" or "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant – Multitenant)" option.


I am now planning to add a log in page. I have a sign-in/sign-up user flow that uses authorization code flow grant and has Entra ID as an external IDP. Is delegated access (access on behalf of Entra user/account) to Graph API possible in this case? If not, is it ok to continue using app-only access?

Hence you cannot register an application which supports user flows as it supports only uses offline_access and openid delegated permissions.

Either make use of other two options to create an application and grant delegated Microsoft Graph API permissions and use of Microsoft Entra ID endpoints to generate the token.
Or you can continue to use app only access.

Check the below to make use of authorization code flow:
Create an application by selecting "Accounts in this organizational directory only (Tenant only - Single tenant)"*  option:

Granted API permissions:

Generated access token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:authorization_code
code:Code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret


By using the above access token, I am able to access Azure AD B2C users:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users



Hi! Thank you for the response. I have two registered applications in the B2C tenant - one for graph API and one with the signin/signup user flow (configured to use authorization code flow grant and has Entra ID as an external IDP).  I am making graph api calls using the SDKs. Right now, I am using client credentials link. I am trying to see how to programmatically use Entra ID token to access Graph API.

Do you want to use client credential flow programmatically? Which language do you need

I am already using client credential flow programmatically and it is working. But now that I have a sign-in page and get a token from AAD, I thought, the "correct" way would be to use a delegated access instead of app-only access. However, I don't know how to do this programmatically. I am using C#.

@sisyphusp check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77986327/how-can-i-get-my-own-user-attributes-email-upn-etc-from-azure-ad-by-using-an/77986510#77986510

Choose any user interactive flow based on your requirement and call the Graph API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#authorization-code-provider

@Rukmini I am trying to implement the interactive flow and I have come across the [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#authorization-code-provider) before but my confusion in that code is : "AUTH_CODE_FROM_REDIRECT"; where do I get that from? Also, I have selected "Accounts in this organizational directory only"  and I am able to see all api permissions that I need.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://xxx
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345

@Rukmini Apologies for reiterating but I do have two applications registered. One with with a sign-in flow using authorization code flow grant and entra id external idp, and another one to access graph API. Basically, I get the entra id token via the first app and I am trying to use that in the second app for a delegated access to Graph API. Is this feasible? If yes, how? Like I said I do have confusions regarding  "AUTH_CODE_FROM_REDIRECT" in the link you forwarded.

Did you check the endpoint I shared in the last comment

And AFAIK  On behalf of flow is feasible for your scenario

Let me know if on behalf of flow works for you

@Rukmini I edited my original post since the comment section wouldn't fit the text.  Kind of confused about the delegated access to be honest (details in the edited section above). Thanks!

As you mentioned the Graph API access is applicable only for Client credential flow not for delegated hence based on your scenario it is not possible to configure an app supporting user flows and then accessing Graph API

Hence you can continue making use of Client credential flow
